# Building a function that can iterate through rows and pull from different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The dataframe is a little simpler than what I'm working with, but I'm trying to write a function that will look at three different budgets in which we have funds. We have a daily spend rate that is consistent, regardless of budget, but look to pull from the first budget first, the second second, etc.  I've started writing the function, but have already run into issues without getting into the larger complexities. The function that I'm trying to create will decrement the respective budget by whatever is spent and return that corresponding value in the "spent" column. If the amount to be spent exceeds the budget, it will pull from the second budget (and then the third), decrementing each respectively.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ID = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Budget_1 = [1000, 1200, 1300, 100 ,500, 0, 800, 950, 4321, 800, 1000, 1200, 1300, 100 ,500, 0, 800, 950, 4321, 800]
Budget_2 = [1000, 1200, 1300, 100 ,500, 0, 800, 950, 4321, 800, 1000, 1200, 1300, 100 ,500, 0, 800, 950, 4321, 800]
Budget_3 = [1000, 1200, 1300, 100 ,500, 0, 800, 950, 4321, 800, 1000, 1200, 1300, 100 ,500, 0, 800, 950, 4321, 800]
FY = [2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019]
Days = [250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250]
spend = [2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 10.0, 2.5, 2.0, 4.0, 2.5, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 10.0, 2.5, 2.0, 4.0, 2.5]
Spent_1 = ''
Spent_2 = ''
Spent_3 = ''
Total_Spent = ''
d = {'ID': ID, 'Budget 1': Budget_1, 'Budget 2': Budget_2, 'Budget 3': Budget_3, 'Fiscal Year': FY, 'Days': Days, 'Spent 1': Spent_1, 'Spent 2': Spent_2, 'Spent 3': Spent_3, 'Total Spent': Total_Spent, 'Spend Rate': spend}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

df = df.sort_values(['Fiscal Year', 'ID'], ascending = True)

def funded_calc(spendrate):
    spent1 = spendrate*df['Days']
    df['Spent 1'] = df['Spent 1'] - spent1
    return spent1

df['Spent'] = df['Spend Rate'].apply(funded_calc)

print(df)
```

Comment: So what is your question? It is kind of unclear where your problem is.

Comment: What would you expect to get as a result from this input data?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
def funded_calc(df):
    s = 0
    df['Spent 1'] = df['Budget 1'] - df['Spend Rate']*df['Days']
    if df['Spent 1'] < 0:
        s = df['Spent 1']
        df['Spent 1'] = 0
    df['Spent 2'] = df['Budget 2'] - df['Spend Rate']*df['Days'] + s
    if df['Spent 2'] < 0:
        s = df['Spent 2']
        df['Spent 2'] = 0
    df['Spent 3'] = df['Budget 3'] - df['Spend Rate']*df['Days'] + s
    df['Total Spent'] = sum([df['Spent 1'], df['Spent 2'], df['Spent 3']])
    return df

df.apply(funded_calc, axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
    Budget 1  Budget 2  Budget 3  Days  Fiscal Year  ID  Spend Rate  Spent 1  \
0       1000      1000      1000   250         2018   1         2.5    375.0   
1       1200      1200      1200   250         2018   2         3.0    450.0   
2       1300      1300      1300   250         2018   3         4.0    300.0   
3        100       100       100   250         2018   4         5.0      0.0   
4        500       500       500   250         2018   5         4.0      0.0   
5          0         0         0   250         2018   6        10.0      0.0   
6        800       800       800   250         2018   7         2.5    175.0   
7        950       950       950   250         2018   8         2.0    450.0   
8       4321      4321      4321   250         2018   9         4.0   3321.0   
9        800       800       800   250         2018  10         2.5    175.0   
10      1000      1000      1000   250         2019   1         2.5    375.0   
11      1200      1200      1200   250         2019   2         3.0    450.0   
12      1300      1300      1300   250         2019   3         4.0    300.0   
13       100       100       100   250         2019   4         5.0      0.0   
14       500       500       500   250         2019   5         4.0      0.0   
15         0         0         0   250         2019   6        10.0      0.0   
16       800       800       800   250         2019   7         2.5    175.0   
17       950       950       950   250         2019   8         2.0    450.0   
18      4321      4321      4321   250         2019   9         4.0   3321.0   
19       800       800       800   250         2019  10         2.5    175.0   

    Spent 2  Spent 3  Total Spent  
0     375.0    375.0       1125.0  
1     450.0    450.0       1350.0  
2     300.0    300.0        900.0  
3       0.0  -3450.0      -3450.0  
4       0.0  -1500.0      -1500.0  
5       0.0  -7500.0      -7500.0  
6     175.0    175.0        525.0  
7     450.0    450.0       1350.0  
8    3321.0   3321.0       9963.0  
9     175.0    175.0        525.0  
10    375.0    375.0       1125.0  
11    450.0    450.0       1350.0  
12    300.0    300.0        900.0  
13      0.0  -3450.0      -3450.0  
14      0.0  -1500.0      -1500.0  
15      0.0  -7500.0      -7500.0  
16    175.0    175.0        525.0  
17    450.0    450.0       1350.0  
18   3321.0   3321.0       9963.0  
19    175.0    175.0        525.0
```

Is it what you want?

I use apply for each raw.

Comment: My code is not reproducing the same results that yours has. I'm still receiving blank columns for the Spent 1-3 and Total.

Comment: Try df = df.apply(funded_calc, axis=1) to save result. Or try add .loc to df before "=". Like: df.loc["Spent 1"] = df["Budget 1"] -... etc.